# Attempt to import only particular character fails

Tags: fonts, symbols

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, systeme}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}


\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigoplus}{1}{mathx}{"C0}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

The above fails because `bigoplus` is already defined. However, I want to overwrite the command, how can I achieve this? For example with only `\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigboxplus}{1}{mathx}{"D0}` the above works fine, only `\bigoplus` and `\bigotimes` seem to cause problems.

Comment: Please extend your example to a full but minimal example others can copy and test.

Comment: You can probably undefine it via `\let\bigoplus\relax`

Comment: @daleif I updated my post, now it's the entire file.

Comment: Your proposal works fine, thanks!